# Method for abstracting filesystems in a C program

Tags: c++, c, filesystems, abstraction

I'm starting out a program in SDL which obviously needs to load resources for the filesystem.
I'd like file calls within the program to be platform-independent. My initial idea is to define a macro (lets call it PTH for path) that is defined in the preprocessor based on system type and and then make file calls in the program using it.
For example

```
SDL_LoadBMP(PTH("data","images","filename"));
```

would simply translate to something filesystem-relevant.

If macros are the accepted way of doing this, what would such macros look like (how can I check for which system is in use, concatenate strings in the macro?)

If not, what is the accepted way of doing this?

Comment: Are you looking for independent of filesystem type (e.g. ext3, ReiserFS, btrfs), or independent of platform (e.g. Windows and Mac and Linux)

Comment: Unless there are some caveats that I don't know of in calling files from exotic filesystems instead of just using a standard Unix path, I'd say platform independent.

Comment: A macro would work on both, I'd think, as would a preprocessor-determined slash-swapping function. That's ugly, but quite clearly not impossible, so I'd rather have a solution for both.

Comment: @Scribble: They are two different languages. Available solutions will vary hugely between them, regardless of what solutions you've pre-assumed. Pick one please.

Comment: Relevant solutions have been given for both in the answers, so I believe there is no reason left to choose. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: You're in to a lot, and I mean **A LOT**, of work trying to write multi-language source files. I suggest you do not mix C and C++ (and Pascal and FORTRAN and COBOL and Lisp and ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Boost Filesystem module](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) is probably your best bet. It has override for the "/" operator on paths so you can do stuff like...

```
ifstream file2( arg_path / "foo" / "bar" );
```

Comment: +1, This is a good recommendation provided you ignore the "C" tag.

Comment: @awoodland: at the point that I see the C++ tag I usually do.

Comment: I would like to have something that works in C as well (which is why I thought of macros), but Blindy has reminded me of glib, which works well in C.

Answer (score 2):

GLib has a number of [portable path-manipulation functions.](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-build-path) If you prefer C++, there's also [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I actually knew of glib, but it slipped my mind. I do prefer C++ to be supported as well, though.

Comment: glib is supported in C++, in that you can use it. boost::filesystem is indeed nicer to use though, if you don't need C support

Comment: +1 since your answer is helpful and relevant, and addresses both c and c++ but Andrew White's is more detailed in its pitch and relevant to most coders (C++), so I'll have to give him the check, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to have this as a macro.

One common approach is to abstract paths to use the forward slash as a separator, since that (almost accidentally!) maps very well to a large proportion of actual platforms. For those where it doesn't, you simply translate inside your file system implementation layer.

Comment: what do you mean by file system implementation layer?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the python implementation for OS9 os.path.join (macpath)

```
def join(s, *p):
  path = s
  for t in p:
    if (not s) or isabs(t):
        path = t
        continue
    if t[:1] == ':':
        t = t[1:]
    if ':' not in path:
        path = ':' + path
    if path[-1:] != ':':
        path = path + ':'
    path = path + t
  return path
```

I'm not familiar with developing under SDL on older Macs. Another alternative in game resources is to use a package file format, and load the resources into memory directly (such as a map < string, SDL_Surface > )

Thereby you would load one file (perhaps even a zip, unzipped at load time)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do the platform-equivalent version of `chdir(data_base_dir);` in your program's startup code, then use relative unix-style paths of the form `"images/filename"`. The last systems where this would not work were MacOS 9, which is completely irrelevant now.